# Search whole inner object in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have two types of data in my DB:

```
{
    "name": "Description",
    "value": "Lorem ipsum"
}

{
    "name": "Properties",
    "value": {
        "type": "Big house",
        "address": "21 Main street",
        "city": "New York"
    }
}
```

And I am trying to implement a search functionality which should return anything inside `value`, for example:

- searching for 'Description' which contains 'Lorem'  **(works)**
- searching for 'Properties' which contains 'Big'     **(doesn't work)**
- searching for 'Properties' which contains 'type'    **(doesn't work)**
- searching for 'Properties' which contains 'address' **(doesn't work)**

My problem is that the search now looks in 'value' and returns only what he finds inside that string, but for 'Properties', the value is an object and the filter returns no results. So basically I need to make mongo search inside the 'value' object as in a string and filter the "Properties" object if I search for "type" for example, or for "house".

My mongoose aggregation code is:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        key: { $first: "$key" },
        fields: {
            $push: {
                "k": "$fields.name",
                "v": "$fields.value"
            }
        }
    },
},
{
    $match: {
        [filter.name]: {
            $regex: filter.value || '',
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

After using the solution provided by Charchit Kapoor, I get the following error, but it doesn't say exactly what's wrong, maybe a feature I use that is not supported in mongoose:

```
[Nest] 150067  - 05/12/2023, 1:50:53 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Feature not supported
MongoServerError: Feature not supported
    at Connection.onMessage (/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:438:20)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:256:56)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (domain.js:532:15)
    at processIncomingData (/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:193:14)
    at MessageStream._write (/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:70:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:745:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
```

I am using it like this now:

```
{
    $match: {
      name: filter.name,
      $expr: {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: {
             $function: {
                body: "function (doc) { return JSON.stringify(doc); }",
                args: [
                  "$value"
                ],
                lang: "js"
             }
          },
          regex: "ips"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Something like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tEWMYxNoHol

Comment: @CharchitKapoor thanks for your answer! It seems be working on the fiddle you sent me, but when I implement it in my app, I get an error. Please check my edited post.

Comment: you will have to enable server-side scripting on mongodb. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I used `input: "hello world"` instead of `$function` and I am getting the same error.

Comment: What is your mongodb version

Comment: db version v6.0.5 on Ubuntu

Comment: Is the database in Atlas? If so then Atlas Search may be a better (and more performance) approach. If not then perhaps change the schema. I don't think your current approach is going to scale well

Comment: Actually, the BD is AWS DocumentDB and I think `$expr` is not supported.

Comment: In that case a schema upgrade is the best

Comment: But I cannot change anything in Mongo, I need to find a way to get the data from the Nest js code :)

Comment: Have you tried using a text index and the $search operator?

Comment: @Joe Can you please provide an example for this? Sorry, I am a mongo/mongoose beginner.

Comment: start with https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/#text-indexes